# BeamSql output format

Tags: apache-beam

The output of my beamSql program is getting written in a file stored in Google storage in below format :

```
BeamRecord [dataValues=[CPSPS02, 0, 1], dataType=BeamRecordSqlType [fieldNames=[SalesComponent, DuetoValue, ModelIteration], fieldTypes=[12, 12, 12]]]
BeamRecord [dataValues=[CPSPS02, 0, 1], dataType=BeamRecordSqlType [fieldNames=[SalesComponent, DuetoValue, ModelIteration], fieldTypes=[12, 12, 12]]] 
BeamRecord [dataValues=[CPSPS02, 0, 1], dataType=BeamRecordSqlType [fieldNames=[SalesComponent, DuetoValue, ModelIteration], fieldTypes=[12, 12, 12]]]
BeamRecord [dataValues=[CPSPS02, 0, 1], dataType=BeamRecordSqlType [fieldNames=[SalesComponent, DuetoValue, ModelIteration], fieldTypes=[12, 12, 12]]]
```

Column names are : SalesComponent, DuetoValue, ModelIteration and their values are CPSPS02, 0, 1 respectively. 
Is it possible that the output should not contain all the extra string like BeamRecord [dataValues=[  ,   dataType=BeamRecordSqlType [fieldNames= ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that the output should not contain all the extra string like BeamRecord [dataValues=[ , dataType=BeamRecordSqlType [fieldNames= ?

Yes.

If you just want the values of the columns you can do access them like this:

```
String salesComponent = beamRecord.getString("SalesComponent");
Integer dueToValue = beamRecord.getInteger("DuetoValue");
Integer modelIteration = beamRecord.getInteger("ModelIteration");
```

You'll have to modify your transform step to do this before writing to GCS.

Reference: [BeamRecord](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/BeamRecord.html)

Comment: This is also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254256